# Xamarin Shell template not listed in VS2017?

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and would like to build my first app using Shell. Using the VS Installer, I updated my VS2017pro and added "Mobile development using .NET" as shown below.

[image]

However, when I create a new Xamarin app, I'm not seeing the Shell option?

[image]

Is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: As far as I know, the "Shell" template is available only in 2019+. But since it is only a template and Xamarin.Forms 4+ is available via nuget, you can just grab one of the Shell example projects from Xamarin's Github repo and use that as a starting point.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks! Looks like you're right. I installed VS2019 Community and it shows up there.